# stopPropagation() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop bubbling when click on image. I cannot set javascript void on href as it is required. I have used stopPropagation but it is not working.

```
function showurl(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    window.location="http://www.yahoo.co.in"
    }

<a href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="http://media.expedia.com/media/content/shared/images/navigation/expedia.co.in.png" onclick="showurl(event)" />
</a>
```

Comment: I think you really want to call `e.preventDefault()`, no?

Comment: An explanation on preventDefault is [here](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

Comment: If you explain why you are substituting new urls, it might lead to a more general solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this was a jQuery question I would suggest never using `onclick` attributes. They only support a single handler and they are are "ugly" (read: harder to find and maintain) :)

```
$('img").onclick = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.location="http://www.yahoo.co.in";
}
```

or

```
$('img").onclick = function() {
     window.location="http://www.yahoo.co.in";
     // return false here does the same as e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault();
     return false;
}
```

As this handler applies to all `img` elements, you may want to data-drive the whole thing (using attributes) like this:

Put the target url in the image as a `data-url` attribute

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="http://media.expedia.com/media/content/shared/images/navigation/expedia.co.in.png"
     data-url="http://www.yahoo.co.in" />
</a>
```

And code-wise:

```
$('img").onclick = function(e) {
     // See if image has a data-url attribute
     var url = $(this).data('url');
     if (url){
         window.location=url;
         // only prevent default if it was an image with a link attribute
         e.preventDefault();
     }
}
```

Comment: I think the code in the OP would work; the symbol "event" should be bound to the event object in the implicit function context for the attribute handler code.

Comment: what about if we need to pass parameter in function

Comment: @amit: That is much cleaner (and maintainable) using attributes. Passing constants to function in `onclick` is a maintenance nightmare. The example above shows using a `data-url` attribute to avoid hard-wiring the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest binding it from JS, even with a basic `onclick` then use `return false;` or  use `preventDefault`. ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s43oxh3a/1/))

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].onclick = function() {
    window.location="http://www.yahoo.co.in";
    return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://media.expedia.com/media/content/shared/images/navigation/expedia.co.in.png" />
</a>
```